# If intersection of closed convex hull is singleton that implies weak convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, convex-hulls

$X$ be a locally convex topological vector space. $\{x_n\}$ converge weakly to $x$ iff $x$ in the closed convex hull of every subsequence of $\{x_n\}$.

I'm able to show the only if part that is if $x_n\xrightarrow{w} x$ then $\{x\}=\cap K_n$ where $K_n= \bar{co}\{x_{n,i}\}_i$, i.e. closed convex hull of subsequence.

How to show the if part?

Comment: If $x_n$ does not converge weakly to $x$ there is a continuous linear functional $f\in X'$ such that the real parts of $f(x_n)$ do not converge to the real parts of $f(x)$. There are thus $\varepsilon >0$ and a subsequence $n(k)$ such that either $\Re f(x_{n(k)}) \le \Re f(x) -\varepsilon$ o $\Re f(x_{n(k)}) \ge \Re f(x)+\varepsilon$. In the first case the closed convex hull of $\{x_{n(k})\}$ is contained in $\{y\in X: \Re f(y)\le \Re f(x)-\varepsilon\}$ which does not contain $x$.